# OpenCV: compute the statistical mode of a set of cv::Mat

Tags: opencv, mode

I am using the following to obtain the statistical mode of a set of cv::Mat:

```
vector<Mat> imgs(30);
...
...

Mat mode = Mat::zeros(imgRows, imgCols, CV_8U);
for(int i=0;i<mode.rows;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<mode.cols;j++)
    {
        vector<int>count(256,0);
        int maxIndex=0, maxCount=0;
        int index;
        for(int n=0;n<imgs.size();n++)
        {
            index = imgs[n].at<uchar>(i,j);
            count[index]++;
            if(count[index] > maxCount)
            {
                maxCount = count[index];
                maxIndex = index;
            }
        }
        mode.at<uchar>(i,j) = maxIndex;
    }
}
```

Is there other ways to compute the mode more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate histogram and use the peak value in the histogram. You can modify the [code already provided by opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html) to calculate mode. This page also explains about histogram and different ways to use it.