# Automatic detection of dominant intensity area in an image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I need some help in detecting the dominant intensity area of an image. Suppose I have the following images and I like to automatically detect the dominant intensity area and find the mean/average intensity value of that dominant area.

Here, in Image-1, the dominant intensity area is the area with light gray color and in Image-2, the dominant area is with the dark gray color. How can I detect the dominant areas in those images and find the mean intensity value of the dominant area.

Image-1: [image]
Image-2: [image]

Any suggestion will be helpful!

**Update:** I used the following codes to get the histogram for Image-2. Figure-3 shows the histogram. Now, I need to find out which bin holds the most of the values i.e. the mode of the histogram. But, couldn't figure out how to calculate the bin with most of the values.

Figure-3: [image]

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    Mat gray=imread("Depth_frames_27/Image23.png",0);
    namedWindow( "Gray", 1 );    imshow( "Gray", gray );

    // Initialize parameters
    int histSize = 256;    // bin size
    float range[] = { 0, 255 };
    const float *ranges[] = { range };

    // Calculate histogram
    MatND hist;
    calcHist( &gray, 1, 0, Mat(), hist, 1, &histSize, ranges, true, false );

    double minVal=0, maxVal=0;
            minMaxLoc(hist, &minVal, &maxVal, 0, 0);
//    cout<<"Max:"<<maxVal<<endl;
//    cout<<"Min:"<<minVal<<endl;

    // Show the calculated histogram in command window
    double total;
    total = gray.rows * gray.cols;
    for( int h = 0; h < histSize; h++ )
         {
            float binVal = hist.at<float>(h);
            cout<<" "<<binVal;
         }

    // Plot the histogram
    int hist_w = 512; int hist_h = 400;
    int bin_w = cvRound( (double) hist_w/histSize );

    Mat histImage( hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC1, Scalar( 0,0,0) );
    normalize(hist, hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    for( int i = 1; i < histSize; i++ )
    {
      line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(hist.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                       Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(hist.at<float>(i)) ),
                       Scalar( 255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
    }

    namedWindow( "Result", 1 );    imshow( "Result", histImage );

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

**Update-2:** Worked out finally! I did the following to get the location and value of the maximum bin of the histogram.

```
double minVal=0, maxVal=0; int minIdx, maxIdx;

    minMaxIdx(hist,&minVal,&maxVal, &minIdx, &maxIdx);
    cout<<"Max:"<<maxVal<<endl;


    cout<<"MaxIdx:"<<maxIdx<<endl;
```

The MaxIdx gives the location of the highest bin of the histogram and that's the dominant intensity value for the image!

Comment: is it always binary the intensities? if not, you may try to do a histogram, find which value has the most intensity and get the position where this value is. You may also select the number of bins depending on how many classes you want to have (for example with 2, you have the case above). If you still have problems I may give you a detailed answer later :)

Comment: @api55: basically, I would convert the image to binary first. Because, I am only concerned with the dominant intensity area; the rest of the image area can be of different intensity. A detailed answer would definitely be of much help :-)

Comment: how do you define "dominant intensity area"? Is it the whole area of light gray in the left image, or only the rectangle area, without the surrounding at right, top and bottom of the darf gray area?

Comment: @Micka: yes, the dominant intensity area for the left image is the light gray area (excluding the dark rectangle). Because, more pixels in this image has the light gray intensity value comparing to the dark gray area. And, for the right image, the dominant area is the dark gray area; because more pixels have the intensity value of dark gray. Do you have any suggestions, how to I detect the dominant intensity area in these images?

Comment: @Tariq: but there are light pixels on top and bottom and right of the dark rectangle, too, in the left image. Do you count them to belong to your dominant intensity area (like a mask), or do you want to ignore them (like a subimage)?

Comment: @Micka: yes, I count them as they belong to the dominant intensity area.

Comment: You can see 2 peeks :) actually 3, but you care only on the biggest one i suppose. At least in this case is quite obvious. You have 256 bins (representing each bin for a color in greyscale). you need to know which bin is the biggest ( in your case each value in `hist`) the position with the highest one is the color of grey with more intensity. The rest of the colors are the ones you do not care. not sure what you want to do afterwards, but you can at least say which color is the dominant one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after is the *mode* of the histogram of intensities (the bin with the highest frequency). It directly tells you the average intensity.

For the given images, the histogram is made of two perfectly sharp peaks.

In some bad cases, the main peak can be spread over several secondary peaks. In such cases, you need to apply smoothing to the histogram before taking the mode.

It can be interesting to look at the relative heights of the first and second maxima, to check how dominant the color is.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Could you please share any sample pseudocode or opencv example code to pursue the idea?

Comment: Pseudocode:
-1. Compute the histogram
-2. Get the histogram mode.

Comment: Exactly what I was aiming with the comments, it depends what is the definition of your dominant intesity. For instance, it could be the highest count, or the highest 5..... for the hist calculation, [here](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/10/histogram-calculation.html) is a tutorial. Then you can see the peacks that @YvesDaoust is talking about. And from there decide which bins to keep (the highest or ....) and that is your dominant color

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I have computed the histogram. Please see the 'Update' section of the post. But, couldn't figure out how to find out which bin holds the most of the values i.e. the mode :-(

Comment: @api55: thanks for your detailed feedback. I have computed the histogram. Please see the 'Update' section of the post. But, couldn't figure out how to find out which bin holds the most of the values i.e. the mode :-(

Comment: @Tariq: searching by yourself is a minimum effort https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474978/opencv-compute-the-statistical-mode-of-a-set-of-cvmat

Comment: Finally it worked out! Please see the "Update-2" section in the original post.